# Why I am getting build fail in my NetBeans project when I tried to build my project?

Tags: java, netbeans, build, ant

I started clean and build my NetBeans project, but it gives me this output that it can't build. My library JAR files are OK and I have checked all my connections.

Here is the output window text

```
ant -f "G:\\My Drive\\newwwwwwww\\NetBeansProjects\\cmp_netbeens\\NetBeansProjects\\flatlaf-dashboard-main" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
init:
deps-clean:
Updating property file: G:\My Drive\newwwwwwww\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory G:\My Drive\newwwwwwww\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: G:\My Drive\newwwwwwww\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build
Updating property file: G:\My Drive\newwwwwwww\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: G:\My Drive\newwwwwwww\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\classes
Created dir: G:\My Drive\newwwwwwww\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\empty
Created dir: G:\My Drive\newwwwwwww\NetBeansProjects\cmp_netbeens\NetBeansProjects\flatlaf-dashboard-main\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
BUILD FAILED (total time: 2 seconds)
```

Why does this fail?

Comment: There is no information in the build output that helps use understand what is going wrong, because there is no error or other diagnostic information. What I do find suspicious is the nesting of your directories (i.e. `NetBeansProjects` in `cmp_netbeens` in `NetBeansProjects`), but I'm not sure how that would cause a problem (except maybe exceeding some path length limitation somewhere).

Comment: I am also worry about the same thing that nothing else is in output window .

Comment: Usually when Ant fails it specifies the line in the script that caused the failure. Could you update your question to include this, along with the contents of your build script?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not positive this is the reason but try to create or move the project in a local directory. The current project is on One Drive, which might affect the building process.

Comment: oh yess its in google drive

Comment: no this error is coming again even its in my local drive

Answer (score 0):

You do not know what is going on, and noone else can help you just because there is not enough information emitted from the build tool. Try to fix that first.

From the menu choose Tools/Options, choose the Java tab. On the subtab Ant you can see a combo box labelled Verbosity Level. Set it to verbose, or even debug and rerun your build.

[image]

Comment: No sorry, I can't find any thing like verbosity any where in IDE. Good news is that I had found a small hint about the problem that when ever I tried to go to the main class and tried to compile it, same output is given, and when I uncheck compile on save and then just save and run the program it gives same Build Failed output but when again checked the box of compile on save and then save and run the program it runs smoothly with output of Build Successfully. I think that if IDE automatically compile it compiles, but when we try to compile manually it makes disturbance. If this is the problem